# How to filter columns which contains something 2 times max and one of them contains something?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this;

```
user - item - ip
user1 - item1 - ip1
user2 - item2 - ip1
user3 - item3 - ip1

user1 - item1 - ip2
user2 - item2 - ip2
```

I want to list every `ip2` which belongs to any user and contains `item2`. Also this `ip2` should be exists in 2 columns max. If it exists more than 2 times such as in `ip1` then don't choose it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Presumably, the middle column has a name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by ip and set the conditions in the having clause:

```
select ip
from tablename
group by ip
having sum(item = 'item2') > 0 and count(*) <= 2 and sum(user = 'user1') > 0;
```

Comment: This is closer. We also need to check if the 2nd item in the list belongs to a specific `user_id`. Can you do that?

Comment: When you say max 2, this means that there can be only 1.

Comment: What happens in that case? Also what if the 2nd has item2 also?

Comment: This is actually the version I want with still that part missing; `select ip from tablename group by server_ip having sum(item = 'item2') > 0 and count(*) = 2`